# What to do if this dialogue comes in terminal in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, package-management, fonts

When I try to install wine through commands this comes in the terminal and I cannot forward after this. What to do?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Tab</kbd> down to the `<Ok>` field and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.